# How to let figure inserted in tkinter entry widget overwrite default in tkinter treeview

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a few code below to insert figure entered in `entry` widget into `tkinter treeview` named `tree2` being selected from `tree1` to overwrite the default figure. Am able to slice to insert `month` but when i insert the `figure` it below the selected `treeview` content and at `column1` not at `column2`. If no figure is entered the default should be `2018`

I appreciate you suggestion to achieve that

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


blow = [("january", "2013"),("february", "2014"),("march", "2015"),("april",
"2016"),("may", "2017")]

def append_select():
    cur_id = tree.focus()
    data = 2018
    data = e1_sub.get()  # if none is provided the default should 2018

    if cur_id:
        tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=data)
       #tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=tree2.column("#2")[data])
        tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=tree.item(cur_id)['values'][:1])


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("columns1", "columns"), show="headings",
selectmode="browse")
tree.heading("#1", text="Month")
tree.heading("#2", text="Year")

for n in blow:
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(n))

tree.pack()

e1_sub = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e1_sub)
e1.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(text="append", command=append_select)
b1.pack()

tree2 = ttk.Treeview(columns=("Month", "Year"), show="headings")
tree2.heading("#1", text="First name")
tree2.heading("#2", text="Surname")
tree2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think your question is a bit unclear, perhaps provide helpful images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
def append_select():
    cur_id = tree.focus()

    data = e1_sub.get()  # if none is provided the default should 2018
    if not data:
        data = 2018

    if cur_id:
        month = tree.item(cur_id)['values'][0]
        tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=(month, data))
```

Basically it first checks if the entry is empty, if so gets 2018, then it simply writes it. Can probably be structured better.

Comment: how will i insert if i have list like this `[("january", "2013", "20-02")]` in tree2 if with three columns

Comment: If tree2 has 3 columns, I think you can do it like `tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=[("january", "2013", "20-02")][0])`.

Comment: @ Nae BIG UPS YOU